# TypeError: Incompatible broadcastable dimensions. Expected (False,), got (True,)

Tags: python, theano, lasagne, batch-normalization

I am working with theano and lasagne.

I am trying to use BatchNorm and I am getting this error. Can someone please guide me, what could be wrong? Or if I can get name of the variable that has this mismatch?

Thanks!

EDIT1:

I am trying to do something like this:

```
inputTarget = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(1,2,32, 32, 32), input_var=T.concatenate([tX, tY], axis=1))
network = lasagne.layers.SliceLayer(inputTarget, indices=slice(0, 1),axis=1) 
tX_new = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
network = lasagne.layers.batch_norm(network)
tY_predicted = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
target= lasagne.layers.SliceLayer(inputTarget, indices=slice(1, None), axis=1)  

tY_new = lasagne.layers.get_output(target)
loss = lasagne.objectives.squared_error(tY_predicted, tY_new).mean()
updates = lasagne.updates.adam(loss, params, learning_rate=lr)
train_fn = theano.function([tX, tY], [tY_predicted, loss, tY_new, tX_new], updates=updates)
```

LOGS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  train_fn = theano.function([tX, tY], [tY_predicted, loss, tY_new, tX_new], updates=updates)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 326, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 449, in pfunc
    no_default_updates=no_default_updates)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 219, in rebuild_collect_shared
    cloned_v = clone_v_get_shared_updates(v, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 219, in rebuild_collect_shared
    cloned_v = clone_v_get_shared_updates(v, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 114, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    allow_convert=False)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py", line 185, in filter_variable
    str(self.broadcastable)))
TypeError: Incompatible broadcastable dimensions. Expected (False,), got (True,).
```

After checking the variables, I know that the code breaks for mean. I am not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Theano does not do broadcasting as numpy does(automatically). You must manually set the dimension that you require to be broadcastable. There is an amazing tutorial given about broadcasting [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/broadcasting.html). If your problem still persists after going through this tutorial, please share your code and the full traceback for me to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already been through this page. After checking I can see the code breaks for mean, but I am not figure out why. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by break for "mean" ?

Comment: I mean that the error comes when the check is being performed for "mean".

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot help you further without seeing your code